# Flutter: TabBar clipped tab titles

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use TabBar with static 4 tabs. I want TabBar to has expanded width on the screen (from right to left edge), but long tab titles clipped like so:

[image]

I tried to use `isScrollable: true` for TabBar. Titles are not clipped but this causes the width to collapse:

[image]

My code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Tabs'), centerTitle: true),
            body: TabBar(tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
              Tab(text: 'Long tab name'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 4'),
            ])));
  }
```

**The question:** how can I achieve full-screen TabBar width with not clipped titles in this case?

Comment: Did you solve this? Also have the same problem

Comment: as far as I remember, no. I didn't find proper answer to do it with TabBar

Answer (score 4):

Make the tabbar scrollable by adding

```
 isScrollable: true,
```

Comment: As I said, I tried to use isScrollable: true for TabBar. Titles are not clipped but this causes the width to collapse. It is not desired behavior. Anyway thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
     @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Tabs'), centerTitle: true),
        body: Container(
          child: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "Tab 1",
                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "Tab 2",
                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "Long tab name sdsadsadas dsadasdsadsa",
                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                "Tab 4",
                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        )));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It's not exactly that I wanted, third tab title is still clipped. Anyway thanks a lot for idea.
I will try to achieve like you this through Tab's child, not text.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a different solution and it may help
just add this property to your Tab bar widget,

**labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),**

worked for me